# Add transparent image over webm video that has transparency

Tags: ffmpeg

We are doing some automation regarding video creation. Idea is that we have one video but we wanna create 1000 videos from that one, each one having a unique number visible on it. Like a water mark. Animator exports the video in MOV (MOV supports alpha channel). The thing is that we need the final videos in webm. I managed to convert MOV to WEBM with `ffmpeg -i video.mov -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt yuva420p output_video.webm` and the output WEBM video is perfect. The issue is when I try to put PNG transparent overlay over it, then the shadows are screwed and transparency is in the toilet. Overlay command: `ffmpeg -i ${inputFileName}.webm -i number_${getHash(imageNumber)}.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=format=auto" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -auto-alt-ref 0 test2.webm` Images have no background.

Any clues?

Steps:

Generate transparent PNG with a label
Convert MOV to WEBM
Put PNG overlay